# Running Keyup and Keydown at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run `split();`, `freeze();` and `freeze2();` when I press the key `x`.
When I first press the key X, `split();` and `freeze();` works. But then when I try again, only `freeze();` works. Is there a way to work all three functions at the same time with a single key?

You'll need to see my script to understand:

```
(function() {
        var speed = 25;

        function split() {
            $("body").trigger($.Event("keydown", {
                keyCode: 32
            }));
        }

        function split2() {
            $("body").trigger($.Event("keyup", {
                keyCode: 32
            }));
        }

        function freeze() {
            $("body").trigger($.Event("keyup", {
                keyCode: 70
            }));
        }

        function freeze2() {
            $("body").trigger($.Event("keydown", {
                keyCode: 70
            }));
        }
        var addEvent = document.addEventListener ? function(target, type, action) {
            if(target) {
                target.addEventListener(type, action, false);
            }
        } : function(target, type, action) {
            if(target) {
                target.attachEvent('on' + type, action, false);
            }
        }
        addEvent(document, 'keydown', function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
            if(key === 88) {
                split();
                setTimeout(speed);
                freeze();
                setTimeout(speed * 2);
                freeze2();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The `setTimeout()` calls are not doing anything. If you want to delay the execution of the functions you must pass them as the first parameter and the delay as the second. Ex: `setTimeout(freeze, speed)`

Comment: Yeah but when I do that, only split(); and freeze(); works

Comment: Plus, it doesn't work the second time I press X